# How to use jCrop on a temporary image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I have a form where you can choose a picture from your harddrive and when you've
chosen the picture it shows instantly on the same page.

I want to use this picture like in the thumbnail demo:
http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail
I also want the jCrop image to change when i change the input file.

This is my PHP-file so far:

```
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script class="jsbin"   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(this.width)
                    .height(this.heigt);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    </head>
    <body>          
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" onchange="readURL(this)" /><br />
    <label for="image">Image:</label>
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />      
    </body>
    </html>
```

This works as I want, but I can't get around how to use this picture with jCrop, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to save the image in a temporary folder, because JCrop works by fetching the original image and cloning it in a custom container where the magic happens.

So you save the POSTed image in a tmp folder with php, you output it in a `<img>` in a `<div id = 'cropbox'>` (per exemple), then `$('#cropbox').Jcrop()`.